# Redefining several time series at once in R

Tags: r

I have 37 time series, and each has 9 columns.
I want to lag 3 of these 9 columns.

Suppose that my time series are named TS1.xts, ..., TS37.xts and I want to do

```
TS1.xts$col1 <- lag.xts( TS1.xts$col1 )
TS1.xts$col1 <- lag.xts( TS1.xts$col1 )
TS1.xts$col3 <- lag.xts( TS1.xts$col3 )
```

Logically, I do not what to write this piece 37 times. I have a list

```
time.series <- c('TS1', ... , 'TS37')
```

And I tried to

```
for(ts in time.series){
  assign(paste0(ts, '.xts$col1'), lag.xts( parse(text=paste0(ts, '.xts$col1'))));
  assign(paste0(ts, '.xts$col2'), lag.xts( parse(text=paste0(ts, '.xts$col2'))));
  assign(paste0(ts, '.xts$col3'), lag.xts( parse(text=paste0(ts, '.xts$col3')))); }
```

But R keeps throwing the following error: '}' unexpected in "}".

I don't understand what this means and I have no idea how to do this code in any other way. I also tried to evaluate the expression inside the `lag.xts()` with `eval()`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you add `dput(TS1)` with expected results. in terms of 1-37 objects I would suggest you change the data structure to a list in the first place, which will allow you to `lapply()` over the members of that list instead of doing some magic with `for` and `paste0()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `get()` inside an `lapply` to retrieve object by name from environment, then update each item's first three columns. The result will be a list equal to *time.series* with modified objects.

```
time.series <- paste0("TS", 1:37, ".xts")

lag_TS_list <- lapply(time.series, function(ts)
                       within(get(ts), {
                            col1 <- lag.xts(col1)
                            col2 <- lag.xts(col2)
                            col3 <- lag.xts(col3)                      
                      })
               )
```

Alternatively use `mget()` to retrieve a list of items and iterate through objects:

```
TS_list <- mget(paste0("TS", 1:37, ".xts"))

lag_TS_list <- lapply(TS_list, function(ts)
                       within(ts, {
                            col1 <- lag.xts(col1)
                            col2 <- lag.xts(col2)
                            col3 <- lag.xts(col3)                      
                      })
               )
```